# Attempting to merge branches returns 'already up to date' despite there being changes

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

I am using git to collaborate on a project. There is a master repository and then we each have our own branches and pull changes from master into them. However, despite the fact that I can see there are changes in the master not present in my branch, I can't get git to bring them in:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

(master) $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

## removed listing of untracked files not relevant to the question ##

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So, my local `master` branch is up to date with the remote `master`. Note that I also have untracked files which are listed in the output of `git status`. I deleted those lines since they're not relevant here.

Now, I switch to my `terdon` branch:

```
(master) $ git checkout terdon
Switched to branch 'terdon'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/terdon'.

(master) $ git status
On branch terdon
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

## removed listing of untracked files not relevant to the question ##

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

As above, the branch is up to date with the remote `terdon` and `status` confirms it. There are, however, changes in `master` that aren't in `terdon`:

```
(terdon) $ git diff terdon master | wc 
   1940    8389   77113  ## loads of differences
```

Attempting to pull them, doesn't work though:

```
(terdon) $ git pull origin master
From github.com:foo/foo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

(terdon) $ git merge master 
Already up-to-date.
```

I did notice that the latest commit in `master` is also in `terdon`, however:

```
$ git log origin/terdon --graph
* commit 800a899fbb88ac16d1856f6d199ffba7817fba6b
| Author: terdon
| Date:   Fri Apr 29 13:09:56 2016 +0200
| 
|     use local tmp dir and allow 12G mem for novosort
|    
*   commit d8c90a8a53ba803be8a5593c4470eed4ac9b6e40
|\  Merge: 7635f22 46edf86
| | Author: terdon
| | Date:   Fri Apr 29 13:03:08 2016 +0200
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'master' of github.com:foo/foo into terdon
| |   
| * commit 46edf86e2329f9351bff291eeb55e8cb13f70031
| | Author: Andreas
| | Date:   Fri Apr 29 09:37:47 2016 +0200
| | 
| |     bug fix with new transcriptomes not having pointer to reference genome
| |
```

And:

```
$ git log origin/master --graph | head
* commit 46edf86e2329f9351bff291eeb55e8cb13f70031
| Author: Andreas
| Date:   Fri Apr 29 09:37:47 2016 +0200
| 
|     bug fix with new transcriptomes not having pointer to reference genome
|
```

That makes me think I did something stupid along the line, but I can't figure out what. How can I bring the changes I know are in the `master` branch into `terdon`?

---

I also tried the suggestions from [Code Wizard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937446/1081936), but there's no change:

```
$ git fetch --all --prune
Fetching origin
From github.com:foo/branch2
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch3
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch4
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch5
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch6
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch7
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch8
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch9
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch10
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch11
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch12
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch13
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch14
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch15
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch16
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch17
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch18
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch19
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch20
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch21
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch22
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/branch23
```

I then ran:

```
$ git log master ^terdon
```

and

```
$ git log ^terdon master
```

but neither had any output.

Comment: What is the output of git status? im willing to bet the content will be in the staging area.

Comment: @CodeWizard I added the output of `git status` run on both branches to the question. I removed some lines which were listing untracked files that are also in the directory. There was nothing else.

Comment: its not status is log!!! `git status` not `git log`!!!.

Comment: @CodeWizard `git log` output is also shown above. I can see that the latest commit from master seems to be listed in the log of terdon, but the changes I want from master aren't there. Um. Help?

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer:

you have changes in the `terdon` branch which are not in master yet.

---

### ***`More details`***

First of all do a full git fetch (will not change anything but its better to be updated)

```
git fetch --all --prune
```

Second of all looks like your all changes are made in `terdon` branch and not on `master` so your `terdon` branch already update with master (it was branches from master i assume).

To verify that this is the actual case, checkout `master` and run a "dry" merge with `terdon`

```
git log ^master terdon
OR
git log master ^terdon
```

depending on the branch you are on and if you want to view pull/push changes.

---

### ***`A Full answer`***

> ***`git diff <branch> <branch>`***

`git diff <branch> <branch>` display the changes between your 2 branches. Looks like you commits have been made to `tredon` but not merged to master. Your master is up to date and the changes are in the new branch.

---

***`How to merge the changes?`***

```
git checkout master
git merge tredon
```

Comment: Thanks, but none of those seem to help (see updated question). My changes are certainly in the master branch. I can see them there when I check the branch out and I can see them in the output of `diff terdon master`. I want to bring those changes *from* master *into* terdon. How would I do this "dry" merge?

Comment: Your code is not commited. its in the statging are. git status will show you the changes, pull will only merge commits

Comment: I don't have any uncommitted changes as far as I know. `git status` would show stashed changes, right? Also, please see the updated question. The latest commit from `master` does appear in the log for `terdon` which suggests that the changes should have been imported. Despite this, the changes aren't there. I'm pretty sure that's very relevant but I can't figure out how/why.

Comment: You have some misunderstanding about git. In git you have the 3 states. working directory & staging area following you to any branch you checkout. Those are not changed when the HEAD is changed. check the status (not log!!!) for uncommitted changes

Comment: I have many misunderstandings about git, I'm very new to it and I really appreciate your help. I have shown the output of `git status` in the question, it tells me everything is up to date and doesn't list any stashed files. I have removed the lines mentioning untracked files since those are not relevant but I show everything else returned by `git status`.

Comment: Yep i see it now in the updates. let me take a look on it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110643/discussion-between-codewizard-and-terdon).